# pattern function in html component

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular, typescript

In my angular 2 app I'm using HTML `pattern=''` to validate a user input.

**Validation.component.html**

```
<input type="text" pattern='[A-Za-z0-9_.\-"()#:{}\\ ]+' required>
```

This is pretty much the breakdown of my current input field. My problem now is that I also want to allow the input of an `'`.

If I use `pattern='[A-Za-z0-9_.\-"()#:{}\\ ']+'` I will get an error because I already use `'` for the `pattern=''` marker.

How can I fix this or can do the trick with an workaround?

Comment: What mean "to validate an user input" ? Maybe it exists a simple solution.

Comment: why don't you write `pattern=""`? in alternative you can escape `'` with `\'`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Or allow an user input, validate is the wrong word.

Comment: @FeMachine The pattern also matches `"`

Comment: Add a double single-quote... `''`  It will resolve it to one when you get the value from the attribute.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx for the duplicate mark, i was to specific with my google attempt i guess. The `' = \x27` solution fixxed my problem.

Do i have to delete my question now?

Comment: No need to remove it, this is not a too common issue. If anyone downvoted it, then I'd consider removing.